# Using simple approximation theorem to show set where measurable function differ from bounded simple function has tiny measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f$ be a measurable function on $[a,b]$ that takes $\pm \infty $ only on a set of measure zero. Show that for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a bounded simple function $\phi$ on $[a,b]$ such that the measure of the set where $f$ and $\phi$ differs is small.  $$m (\{ x : |f(x) -\phi (x)| \geq \epsilon\}) < \epsilon \tag{*} $$

I know the Simple Approximation Theorem (SAT) states that a measurable function can be approximated by a sequence of simple functions. In this case, how do I show $(*)$ is true? I am using the Royden Fitzpatrick book but the proof for SAT is not very useful here.

Answer (score 2):

For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let $E_n=\{|f|\geq n\}$. Then $E_{n+1}\subset E_n$ for all $n$. And by continuity of measure $$0=m(\{f=\pm\infty\})=m\biggl(\bigcap_nE_n\biggr)=\lim_nm(E_n)$$ So there exists $n_0$ such that $m(E_n)<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Choose $n\geq n_0$ with $n>1/\varepsilon$. Now let
$$
\phi(x)=\sum_{j=-n^2}^{n^2-1}\frac{j}{n}\,1_{\{\frac jn\leq f<\frac{j+1}n\}}.
$$
Outside of $E_n$, we have $|f-\phi|<\tfrac1n<\varepsilon$. Thus
$$
\{|f-\phi\|\geq\varepsilon\}\subset E_n.
$$

Comment: I can understand the proof but I am wondering how to construct the simple function function $\phi$ as above (this was not obvious to me) in order to show that the set where $f$ and $\phi$ differs is less than $\epsilon$. Thanks.

Comment: The set is the complement of $E_n$.

Comment: Ok I understand the reasoning for the set where the difference between the two functions is greater than $\epsilon$ is tiny and goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: The point is that simple functions are bounded; so you cannot approximate an unbounded function uniformly. So one gets the $E_n$ with small measure, and outside of $E_n$ the function $f$ is bounded and can be approximated by a simple function.